# Apache rewrites custom reason phrases in HTTP header to a standard one

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm sending errors from my PHP script using

```
function http_error($message) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 ERROR $message!");
    die();
}
```

My local apache server on Windows correctly sends me HTTP header with a custom message like this:

> HTTP/1.1 500 ERROR Field count doesn't match!!

But my customer's server ignores any additional message and always sends header as

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Why can this happen? Is there any Apache directive to overwrite header custom messages? This server is controlled by CPanel/WHM btw. But I didn't find any such an option in an EasyApache build settings in WHM.

I'm using Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.10.

Comment: Check the logs for your customer's server. It's most likely not ignoring the additional message but in fact encountering an internal server error.

Comment: @David Schwartz No, I've added a logging line before `http_error()` calls. Control reaches this line and header is indeed sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't apache, but some proxy server between me and customer's server. The same proxy was between my customer and his server by chance.